# Rescue exception thrown by a redirect_to :back

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Little background information: I have a project with authenticated users which can have multiple 'scopes' of data. A scope determines which records can and can't be accessed by a user. A logged in user is always subsribed to a single scope stored in the session.

A user can at any time switch between the scopes he has access to, regardless of which page he is on.

After a scope switch I would like to *try* to reload the same page by using `redirect_to :back`. This is not always possible, since the current scope might not allow access to the page that was previously being viewed.

In those cases, the controller in question will throw an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception in the respective controller on the `.find(params[:id])` call, which is very ugly. I would very much like to gracefully fallback to a `redirect_to :root` with an accompanying alert message.

Currently I have this, but this does not work:

```
  def switch_scope
    s = current_client.scopes.find(params[:scope_id])
    set_scope(s.id)
    begin
      flash[:notice] = 'Scope switched succesfully.'
      redirect_to :back # <= This might throw NotFoundException
    rescue
      flash[:alert] = 'Scope switched. Page could not be reloaded'
      redirect_to :root
    end
  end
```

**EDIT** 
For example, the `redirect_to :back` might go back to this show Product function:

```
def show
  @product = Product.where(scope_id: session[:scope_id]).find(params[:id])
end
```

As you can see, it first filters all propducts based on the selected scope in the session. Then it does a find(ID) on that subset. It is very possible that after a scope switch the Product with said ID is no longer accessible, giving a `RecordNotFoundException`.

Now again, this is an example and many of these constructions exists in my application, so preferably I do not want to edit it on this side manually.

Comment: When the request has been redirected to :back, why does that raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. What I meant to say is, can you modify the logic on that end so that it will not raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` on `.find(params[:id])`? Can you add this part of controller code in your question? That will help me inspect better.

Comment: Please add the code that actually raises the exception in your controller  (I guess it's trying to find something with the scope applied) so that we can be more specific with possible solutions.

Comment: `def index Product.find(0) end`. There, that is an exampe that throws an exception...

Comment: Jay-Ar Polidario, since I don't know in advance which page `redirect_to :back` will go to, since a scope switch can be invoked from any page, it is not an option to fix it on that side, since I need to add a custom hack in a lot of places. Not really a Rails DRY way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Add This in the **application_controller.rb**

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
 if (params[:controller]=="your_controller_name" && params[:action] == "Your method")
  flash[:alert] = "Access denied. You are not authorized to access the requested page."
  redirect_to root_path
 end
end
```

OR

```
def switch_scope
    s = current_client.scopes.find(params[:scope_id])
    set_scope(s.id)
    begin
      flash[:notice] = 'Scope switched succesfully.'
      redirect_to :back # <= This might throw NotFoundException
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      flash[:alert] = 'Scope switched. Page could not be reloaded'
      redirect_to :root
    end
end
```

Comment: That will gracefully redirect *all* RecordNotFound exceptions. In this case I would only like this gracefull fallback in the specific case of the switch_scope function

Comment: Please second one I have make changes

Comment: Sadly that does not work. It seems that a redirect_to just tells the client to make a new request to the server which makes a completely new flow of control beyond the scope of a single begin/rescue block.

I think I have to use your first solution, but hack it somewhat to make sure it only triggers if we are coming from a scope_switch and raise the error normally otherwise

Comment: Now I make hack in this method

Comment: Considering params[:controller] and params[:action] contain information about the current request, and not the request we just got redirected from, this is also not a solution for my situation.